# how to handle array in ng-model in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

**array:**

```
getRoles =[{"id":3,"role":"role1"},{"id":4,"role":"role2"},{"id":6,"role":"role3"}]
```

HTML:

```html
<form ng-submit="userRegister()" name="registrationForm" id="registrationForm">
  <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="role in getRoles">
    <label ng-init="i=i+1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="flat" ng-model="registrationData.role_ids[i]" ng-value="{{role.id}}">{{role.role}}
    </label>{{registrationData.roles_id}}</div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

In the above html variable `i` is not working. In every loop it will print `i`, not value of `i`.
Need: I want to submit the form and will get name and value of selected checkbox in controller. kindly help me. I appreciate all response.

Comment: I think in your case you can use `$index` of `ng-repeat`. Since your input is already inside `ng-repeat` for `ng-model` you can directly use `role.id`.

Comment: thanks for you response. it work but I can not Identify which role selected by user. because array will not attached role id. kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `ngRepeat` creates a new scope on every iteration which initializes it's own `i`, so `i=i+1` isn't likely to be evaluated to a valid integer.

You can use the `$index` property to access the iteration index instead like:

```html
<form ng-submit="userRegister()" name="registrationForm" id="registrationForm">
  <div class="checkbox" ng-repeat="role in getRoles">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="flat" ng-model="registrationData.role_ids[$index]" ng-value="{{role.id}}">{{role.role}}
    </label>{{registrationData.roles_id}}</div>
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks it work. but How can I get id in controller? right now I will get array [role_ids] => {"3":true,"4":true,"5":true} in controller.

Comment: with the help of this array I can not Identify which role selected by user.

Comment: @PrashantShukla change `ng-value="{{role.id}}` to `ng-value="{{role.role}}` ? or if role id's are unique, and `role_ids` an object : `ng-model="registrationData.role_ids[role.id]"` ?